# mail command always pointing to root's file

Tags: linux, email

I am trying to configure a postfix mail server.
Mail for the root are accessible.
But while checking the mail for non root users, I get the following error

> /var/spool/mail/root: Permission denied

File `/var/spool/mail/$USER` is present for the respective user but still the mail command refers to the root's file.

Output of postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mail_spool_directory = /var/spool/mail
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain,
mydomain = domain.in
myhostname = server.domain.in
mynetworks = 166.64.32.22, 127.0.0.0/8
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

Comment: Hi I have updated the log file

Comment: Whoops, sorry :( . Looks like I misread your question this morning. Actually it has nothing to do with mail server/postfix. The problem is in client side a.k.a `mail` program.

Comment: No I was unable to resolve, $MAIL is /var/spool/mail/root for all the users

Comment: I see. So in your case, `$MAIL` variable was overridden by something. Perhaps you can find it in `/etc/` directory. Can you post the output of `grep -R MAIL /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/  /etc/bashrc`?

Comment: Her's the output:
/etc/profile:    MAIL="/var/spool/mail/$USER"
/etc/profile:export PATH USER LOGNAME MAIL HOSTNAME HISTSIZE HISTCONTROL

Comment: Did you use `su myuser` command to login as myuser account? Or did you has tried login via `ssh myuser@myip`?

Comment: i am using su myuser

Comment: Okay, try to use `su - myuser` (dash between su and myuser). What's the output of command `echo $MAIL`?

Comment: the output is /var/spool/mail/myuser 
thanks a lot it works now !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*So, the problem here isn't related with postfix at all. Postfix in server side behaves correctly but the mail client is misbehaves.*

By default [`mail` command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mail) in will use `$MAIL` environment variable to determine the location of mailbox (unless you tell it explicitly using `-f` parameter). In CentOS bash shell , the default value of $MAIL variable is `/var/spool/mail/$USER`. Snippet from `man mail`.

> **MAIL**
>
> Is used as the user's mailbox, if set. Otherwise, a system-dependent default is used. Can be a protocol:// string (see the folder command for more information).

[OP states in the comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/693107/mail-command-always-pointing-to-roots-file#comment857293_693107) that he used `su myuser` from root user to change user on the shell. Unfortunately, this has some effect. Variable $MAIL still point into `/var/spool/mail/root`. So, the mailbox path hasn't changed but the previlige has been drop to non-root user.

To address the issue, you can use `su -l myuser` to change user on the shell. Snippet from `man su`.

> **-, -l, --login**
>
> make the shell a login shell

Without `-l`, the environment variable won't change itself.

Conclusion: both software (postfix and bsd-mailx) was behaves correctly. The problem is OP who fail to set environment variable prior changing user.

Comment: I have just had this issue and confirmed that what you say is true. Thank you :).